Replicating ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
I am trying to replicate an issue we recently faced. We have a PL/SQL procedure that has the logic below:
procedure mark_records (p_request_id number)
is
begin
    
    -- this marks which contracts are going to be processed
    update  jisip_agreements jp
    set     jp.request_id = p_request_id
    where exists (select 1 from
                    jisip_eligible_transactions x
                    jisip_eligible_suppliers y
                    jisip_eligible_schedules z
                    where x.schedule_id = z.schedule_id 
                    and y.supplier_id = x.supplier_id
                    and jp.agreement_id = y.agreement_id);
    
    -- additional processing --

    -- this unmarks the contracts were already processed        
    update  jisip_agreements
    set     request_id = null
    where   request_id = p_request_id;
    

end;
/

This program basically "marks" those records in jisip_agreements to be processed, does some additional processing (i.e. inserts into table X), then later on those same records will be "unmarked" once processing is completed.
One of our clients is running this process 6-10 times simultaneously and concurrently within an hour and is causing a ORA-00060 deadlock issue.  We already have a fix in mind (i.e. Autonomous Transaction, additional filters, etc.), but we are unable to replicate the issue internally and it always completes successfully. We want to replicate it before moving the fix to Production.
I created a mock test in a local Database to replicate it, but in a slightly different approach:
Session 1:
set serveroutput on;
begin
    
    update  jisip_agreements
    set     request_id = 345435345
    where   agreement_id = 1;    
    
    dbms_session.sleep(5);
    
    update  jisip_agreements
    set     request_id = 345435345
    where   agreement_id = 2;        
      
end;
/

Session 2
set serveroutput on;
begin
    
    update  jisip_agreements
    set     request_id = 12345
    where   agreement_id = 2;    
    
    dbms_session.sleep(5);
    
    update  jisip_agreements
    set     request_id = 12345
    where   agreement_id = 1;
    
end;
/

I am getting the expected error:
 Error report - ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource  
 ORA-06512: at line 9  
 00060. 00000 -  "deadlock detected while waiting for resource"  
 *Cause:    Transactions deadlocked one another while waiting for resources.  
 *Action:   Look at the trace file to see the transactions and resources  
            involved. Retry if necessary.

How can I replicate the ORA-0060 issue using the procedure?

You might avoid the issue by just adding and request_id is null to the first update, so two simultaneous runs don't try to 'mark' the same row? Anyway... it's unclear why you can't replicate, if two sessions call the procedure at almost the same time; assuming it it that table causing it, and your 'additional processing' takes long enough. Are other things modifying/locking the table you insert into in production? Maybe simulating that (an uncommitted insert in a third session) might help?

Has your client sent you the deadlock trace file so that you can confirm exactly what is causing the deadlock?  So you know that it is, in fact, the two update statements in your procedure and not something in the "additional processing"?  What does the deadlock trace show is the issue?  It seems odd that in your procedure, your first update statement updates every row in the table.

@JustinCave yes, a tracefile shows that the deadlock occurs in the first update statement. it is the query being shown in the Global Wait-For-Graph (WFG) report.

@MigsIsip - OK.  And what is the other session waiting on?  Are you sure that you intended the first update statement to update every row in the table unconditionally?  That seems weird functionally if this procedure is intended to be called by multiple sessions simultaneously.

@JustinCave i have added more information on the code that would clarify the update statement. It's actually an EXISTS that marks all rows to be processed.

@AlexPoole there are no updates/inserts into the jisip_agreements table in the processing part, it just uses the marked records as a filter, then later on inserts into another table "X". once processing is done, it gets unmarked.

Is it possible that the runs at your client are "overlapping" e.g. the next one starts before the previous one is finished? Are your reproduction database and client database similar enough that the amount of data is not an issue while reproducing this? Maybe your client has much more concurrent activity in the production db?

Additionally I don't know if you need the value of request_id in your additional processing but you could maybe skip this altogether by refactoring to use a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE cursor and a FOR-loop with the additional logic in the loop.

@Migs In the trace file, in addition to finding the relevant statements, also look for the relevant objects. For example, it's possible the deadlock is cased by a bitmap index. The trace file should include the relevant OBJECT_ID.

@MartinSchapendonk yes, this is definitely the case, they are running those jobs simultaneously and concurrently. They also have much more data in their Production Environment, which makes it reproducible from their end.
